# How to compress imported column types in R

Tags: r

My code for importing a specific file so far looks like

```
df <- read_excel("File path", 
       col_types = c("numeric", "text", "numeric", 
         "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
         "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
         "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
         "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
         "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
         "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
         "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
         "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
         "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
         "text", "text", "text", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
         "numeric", "numeric", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
         "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text"), 
       skip = 8)
```

How would I go about compressing specifically the "col types" sections but still keeping the same effect. I've tried `sapply(df, as.numeric)`, but this changes all columns to numeric where I specifically need the second to be text.

Note: I understand other columns besides the second have "text", the example is a halfway point of my attempt.

Comment: `col_types = c("numeric", "text", 
  rep("numeric", 4), rep("text", 67), 
  rep("numeric", 6), rep("text", 13))`     would be tidier.

Comment: What is the use case behind your question? Do you just want to reduce the amount of characters you have to type (which is absolutely legitimate to ask)?

Comment: Yes it is @RYoda , it seems like the solution was provided below though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `read_excel` will guess the types for you but if that does not work on your spreadsheet:

**1) rep** Use `rep` like this:

```
col_types <- rep(c("numeric", "text", "numeric", "text", "numeric", "text"),
                 c(1L, 1L, 4L, 67L, 6L, 13L))

# test - col_types_orig defined in Note at end
identical(col_types, col_types_orig) 
## [1] TRUE
```

**2) rle**  We can also compress using `rle` and then uncompress using `inverse.rle`:

```
r <- rle(col_types_orig)
col_types <- inverse.rle(r)

identical(inverse.rle(r), col_types_orig)
## [1] TRUE
```

You can get `r` as R code using `dput(r)`. (In fact we got the arguments to `rep` in (1) by examining this `dput` output.)

**3)**  Noting that there are 92 elements in `col_types_orig` and all are text except for a few numeric we can do this:

```
length(col_types_orig)
## [1] 92

table(col_types_orig)
## col_types_orig
## numeric    text 
##      11      81 

which(col_types_orig == "numeric")
## [1]  1  3  4  5  6 74 75 76 77 78 79

col_types <- replace(rep("text", 92), c(1, 3:6, 74:79), "numeric")

identical(col_types, col_types_orig)
 ## [1] TRUE
```

**Note:**

```
col_types_orig <- 
c("numeric", "text", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
"text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
"text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
"text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
"text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
"text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
"text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
"text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
"text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
"text", "text", "text", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
"numeric", "numeric", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
"text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy to take two steps to do the import you could read all in first as text and then convert the relevant columns to numeric using `dplyr::mutate_at`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

df <- read_excel("File path", col_types = "text", skip = 8) %>%
  mutate_at(c(1, 3:6, 74:79), as.numeric)
```